# Regex: como selecionar frase inteira (sem digitos) e inserir aspas

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

Eu tenho esse resultado de um .csv

```
9   Abraço de tamanduá
9   Abraço fraterno
9   Correr/partir pro abraço (futebol)
```

Estou aplicando diversos regex para que o resultado final seja uma instrução SQL assim:

```
INSERT INTO `expressoes`(`id_palavra`, `expressao`) VALUES (9, 'Abraço de tamanduá'), (9, 'Abraço fraterno'), (9, 'Correr/partir pro abraço (futebol)')
```

Como sou *newbie* em **regex**, fiz um `keybinding` no vscode para executá-lo com um atalho (usando o `find` e `replace all` do vscode). Assim eu consigo executar diversos comandos regex em sequência.

Assim, no primeiro comando eu fiz:

```
find: \n{1,}
replace all: ), (
```

Resultando:

```
9   Abraço de tamanduá), (9 Abraço fraterno), (9    Correr/partir pro abraço (futebol)
```

O segundo comando:

```
find: (?<=[0-9])
replace all: ,
```

Resultando

```
9,  Abraço de tamanduá), (9,    Abraço fraterno), (9,   Correr/partir pro abraço (futebol)
```

Depois, os comandos 3, 4 e 5:

```
find: ^
replace all: (

find: $
replace all: )

find: \s // isso não funciona pelo plugin `ssmacro` que executa o comando regex
replace all: ␣ // corrigir `tab` com um espaço simples
```

só para corrigir o inicio e o final com parenteses. Resultando:

```
(9, Abraço de tamanduá), (9, Abraço fraterno), (9, Correr/partir pro abraço (futebol))
```

Agora, inserir as aspas simples na frase inteira eu não estou entendendo. Tentei `([a-z,A-z,çéáíãõ]+)` `(\w+)` tb não deu. Consegui um próximo com esse:

```
find: ([^\d\W]+á*é*í*ó*ú*õ*ã*ç*(\s)*/*)
replace: '$1'
```

mas ainda não deu certo. resultando:

```
(9, 'Abraç''o ''de ''tamanduá'), (9, 'Abraç''o ''fraterno'), (9, 'Correr/''partir ''pro ''abraç''o '('futebol'))
```

Q: Alguma ideia para formatar corretamente as aspas simples?

Q: E ainda tem essa `(...)` como em `(futebol)` no final de algumas sentenças que eu não faço ideia em como isolá-lo.

Comment: Você quer remover da sentença tudo que vem antes do início da frase(o espaço e o dígito)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seria mais fácil usar alguma linguagem para ler o CSV, separar os campos e criar os inserts, mas se quer fazer com regex, vamos lá.

Uma opção é usar `(\d+)\s+(.+)`:

- `\d+`: um ou mais dígitos
- `\s+`: um ou mais espaços
- `.+`: um ou mais caracteres (["qualquer um", exceto quebras de linha](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) - ou seja, vai até o final da linha)

Os dígitos e os caracteres depois do espaço estão entre parênteses para formar [grupos de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), assim eu consigo pegá-los posteriormente.

Na substituição você usa:

```
INSERT INTO `expressoes`(`id_palavra`, `expressao`) VALUES ($1, '$2');
```

Os trechos `$1` e `$2` equivalem aos grupos de captura (o primeiro são os dígitos e segundo é o restante do texto).

Só que isso vai gerar várias linhas com um `INSERT` em cada, e não apenas um único `INSERT` como você queria. Mas se quiser, você pode substituir por `VALUES ($1, '$2'),` e adicionar o `INSERT INTO etc...` no início manualmente.